# How to change the color of a box next to the box I click on in a grid

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 5x5 grid and each box can turn black or white whenever you click on it. This grid simulates the lights out game and so far I am only able to change the color of only the box I am clicking on but I need to also change the color of the boxes 1 length away horizontally and vertically.

I have a feeling I need to make the grid into an array using javascript but I don't know how to do that. The following code is what I have so far.

```js
var grid = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

Array.from(grid).forEach(click => click.addEventListener("click", function changeColor() {
    if (click.style.background === 'black') {
        click.style.background = "white";
    } else {
        click.style.background = "black";
    }
}));
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Lights Out Game</title>
  <link href="lights_out.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="module" src="Lightsout.js?v=5"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <h1>Lights Out</h1>
  <button type="button">Reset board</button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <article> Click on each box until all the boxes are black.</article>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the click action will affect several boxes by calling `changeColor`, it's better to separate it from the event listener

```
const changeColor = function(box){
    if (box.style.background === 'black') {
        box.style.background = "white";
    } else {
        box.style.background = "black";
    }
}
```

You'll still need an event handler assigned which we will, very creatively, call `clickHandler`

```
Array.from(grid).forEach(box => click.addEventListener("click", () => clickHandler(box)))
```

It'll be useful to differentiate each box; it can be done by adding an `id` attribute to each of them while also assigning the listener so the line above becomes

```
Array.from(grid).forEach(
    (box, index) => {
        box.addEventListener("click", () => clickHandler(box))
        box.id = index
    }
)
```

Finally you'll need to determine which of the boxes need to change when one is clicked. This can be defined in the `clickHandler` function

```
let boxes = Array.from(grid)

const clickHandler= function(box){
    // get the box id, which will coincide with its position in the array
    index = parseInt(c.id)

    // determine the adjacent boxes' indexes
    up = index - 5
    down = index + 5
    left = index - 1
    right = index + 1

    // Make sure the index is not out of bounds and change color
    if(up > 0)
        changeColor(boxes[up])
    if(down < 25)
        changeColor(boxes[down])

    // Make sure the left and right indexes are in the same row
    if(Math.floor(index / 5) == Math.floor(left / 5))
        changeColor(boxes[left])
    if(Math.floor(index / 5) == Math.floor(right / 5))
        changeColor(boxes[right])

    // change the color of the box that was clicked
    changeColor(boxes[index])
}
```

All put together it should be something like this:

```js
const grid = document.getElementsByClassName('box')
const changeColor = function(box){
    if (box.style.background === 'black') {
        box.style.background = "white";
    } else {
        box.style.background = "black";
    }
}

Array.from(grid).forEach(
    (box, index) => {
        box.addEventListener("click", () => clickHandler(box))
        box.id = index
    }
)

let boxes = Array.from(grid)

const clickHandler= function(box){
    // get the box id, which will coincide with its position in the array
    index = parseInt(box.id)

    // determine the adjacent boxes' indexes
    up = index - 5
    down = index + 5
    left = index - 1
    right = index + 1

    // Make sure the index is not out of bounds and change color
    if(up > 0)
        changeColor(boxes[up])
    if(down < 25)
        changeColor(boxes[down])

    // Make sure the left and right indexes are in the same row
    if(Math.floor(index / 5) == Math.floor(left / 5))
        changeColor(boxes[left])
    if(Math.floor(index / 5) == Math.floor(right / 5))
        changeColor(boxes[right])

    // change the color of the box that was clicked
    changeColor(boxes[index])
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Lights Out Game</title>
  <link href="lights_out.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="module" src="Lightsout.js?v=5"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <h1>Lights Out</h1>
  <button type="button">Reset board</button>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>

  <article> Click on each box until all the boxes are black.</article>
 </body>
```